# From wind speed to Watt

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have this graph below which show how much effect a windspeed make i Watt. My question is. How can I convert wind speed into Watt without reading the graph.

[image]

Comment: I just work with wind turbines, and want to know if there is a mathematical way instead of reading the graph every time I want to know the effect to a given windspeed.

Comment: I dont know, just fairly representative I think

Comment: Yes it is okay to say $x\ge12$ but $\approx5000$

Comment: You can play with the numbers (I start at $x = 3$) and we already discussed for $x \ge 12$. This gives three different fits and you can plot each one, although those are shown too. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fit+%7B%7B3%2C0%7D%2C%7B4%2C200%7D%2C%7B5%2C700%7D%2C%7B6%2C+1100%7D%2C%7B7%2C+1800%7D%2C%7B8%2C2500%7D%2C%7B9%2C3400%7D%2C%7B10%2C4100%7D%2C%7B11%2C4900%7D%7D

Comment: Okay thanks this is actually useful